# How to fix frequent crashes of openshot?

Tags: ubuntu

I have been using the `openshot` video editing software for some time on Ubuntu 13.10, which does not run stable for me. I would like to know if I can do something to stabilize it, so I can actually use it for video editing...

The version used is 1.4.3, and below I post a recent backtrace.

Maybe the crashes are related to some other libraries, so if you need to extra information please provide a way how to get this information.

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x000000000370c920 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80996)[0x7ff8c2ed7996]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(gdk_region_union+0x97)[0x7ff8bfeaf487]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x3cb7d)[0x7ff8bfeb9b7d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x23d090)[0x7ff8c036c090]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x242a1c)[0x7ff8c0371a1c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_widget_queue_resize+0x68)[0x7ff8c0371ab8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__OBJECTv+0x77)[0x7ff8c0e27257]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x103b7)[0x7ff8c0e243b7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0x442)[0x7ff8c0e3ce82]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7ff8c0e3dae2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x242f45)[0x7ff8c0371f45]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_run_dispose+0x60)[0x7ff8c0e2a8a0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x1f1eb5)[0x7ff8c0320eb5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(+0x1f2668)[0x7ff8c0321668]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_closure_invoke+0x138)[0x7ff8c0e24188]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x21337)[0x7ff8c0e35337]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit_valist+0xde9)[0x7ff8c0e3d829]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_signal_emit+0x82)[0x7ff8c0e3dae2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x14505)[0x7ff8c0e28505]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_notify+0x16b)[0x7ff8c0e2aabb]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/_gtk.so(+0x148730)[0x7ff8c08b3730]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x435)[0x561125]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xc9a)[0x56198a]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xc9a)[0x56198a]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xc9a)[0x56198a]
/usr/bin/python[0x556cea]
/usr/bin/python[0x4b5164]
/usr/bin/python(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x6b)[0x4d997b]
/usr/bin/python[0x584b42]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x7f6e)[0x7ff8c3226f6e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7ff8c2f519cd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-006ba000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 4201204                            /usr/bin/python2.7
008b9000-008ba000 r--p 002b9000 08:07 4201204                            /usr/bin/python2.7
008ba000-0092e000 rw-p 002ba000 08:07 4201204                            /usr/bin/python2.7
0092e000-00941000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01dbe000-047b3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff850000000-7ff8503c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8503c2000-7ff854000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff856ffe000-7ff856fff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff856fff000-7ff8577ff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6260]
7ff8577ff000-7ff857800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff857800000-7ff858000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6261]
7ff858000000-7ff85822b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff85822b000-7ff85c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff85c000000-7ff85c3ab000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff85c3ab000-7ff860000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff860000000-7ff86022c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86022c000-7ff864000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff864000000-7ff86408e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86408e000-7ff868000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff868000000-7ff869f03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff869f03000-7ff86c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86dffb000-7ff86dffc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86dffc000-7ff86e7fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6238]
7ff86e7fc000-7ff86e7fd000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86e7fd000-7ff86effd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6237]
7ff86effd000-7ff86effe000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86effe000-7ff86f7fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6232]
7ff86f7fe000-7ff86f7ff000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff86f7ff000-7ff86ffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6262]
7ff86ffff000-7ff874000000 rw-s 00000000 00:14 154498                     /run/shm/pulse-shm-2289669443
7ff874000000-7ff874450000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff874450000-7ff878000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff878000000-7ff878198000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff878198000-7ff87c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff87c000000-7ff87c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff87c021000-7ff880000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff880758000-7ff88080d000 r--p 00000000 08:07 5243501                    /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
7ff880b01000-7ff88158f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff88158f000-7ff881590000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff881590000-7ff882094000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6233]
7ff882094000-7ff882095000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff882095000-7ff882895000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6263]
7ff882895000-7ff8828f5000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 7503895                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7ff8828f5000-7ff882ffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff8837ff000-7ff883800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff883800000-7ff884000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6223]
7ff884000000-7ff88409f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff88409f000-7ff888000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff888000000-7ff888231000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff888231000-7ff88c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff88c000000-7ff88c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff88c021000-7ff890000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff89003c000-7ff8901de000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 7634961                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7ff89095f000-7ff8909df000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 10387474                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7ff8909df000-7ff890ae0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff890ae0000-7ff890ae1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff890ae1000-7ff8912e1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:6220]
7ff8912e1000-7ff891341000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 7340048                    /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7ff891341000-7ff891353000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 4590283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7ff891353000-7ff891552000 ---p 00012000 08:07 4590283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7ff891552000-7ff891554000 r--p 00011000 08:07 4590283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7ff891554000-7ff891555000 rw-p 00013000 08:07 4590283                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
7ff891555000-7ff89157a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 4589183                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
7ff89157a000-7ff89177a000 ---p 00025000 08:07 4589183                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
7ff89177a000-7ff89177f000 r--p 00025000 08:07 4589183                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
7ff89177f000-7ff891780000 rw-p 0002a000 08:07 4589183                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so
[3]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) openshot
```

Comment: i experienced the same problem, and after trying to fix or at least mitigate it, and being unable to, i ended up leaving OpenShot and using something else instead :(  shame :(

Comment: And what exactly are you using now instead?

Comment: I wish someone had warned me about this. Spent an amount of timing putting together a nice timeline but now I can't export it to anything. Utterly useless.

Comment: It happened to me as well, it was solved when I upgraded to 2.4.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Report the bug in Launchpad if you have not done this yet.
2. While it is being fixed (something which may never happen :-P):

   - Try other version of OpenShot (package downgrade or download and install from source; you could try the [latest development release](https://code.launchpad.net/~openshot.code/openshot/main)).
   - Try other software (as Kdenlive; it seems to be a [more active](http://www.ohloh.net/p/kdenlive) project [than OpenShot](http://www.ohloh.net/p/openshot-video-editor)).
   - Try other distribution (as Fedora or Debian/Mint if you like Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Openshot was unstable for me as well, and there's quite a number of forum posts that mention frequent crashing as well. I do not know how to fix the crash you're getting, but here's a few suggestions that you might try:

- Update graphics drivers if you're using a video card.
- Reinstall Openshot using `apt-get purge` (to get rid of config files).
- Use a different video editor. This doesn't fix the crashing, but if nothing works (like for me), then it might be a good idea to try another program if it has all the features you need. [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) is a good alternative feature-wise. It's missing some features in Openshot, but if you're not using any of these, then kdenlive should do the job . Here's the [feature list](http://www.kdenlive.org/features) from the official site.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the causes of Openshot crashes have largely been due to codec issues. I get around this with a few tricks:

1. update Ffmpeg, MLT, and Openshot. That makes sure that you have the latest support for all the latest developments in video formats.
2. transcode your videos to "simpler" formats (in other words, if you are editing lots of AVCHD footage, then re-encode it to something like xvid, which, being open source, has really solid open source support).
3. Use Kdenlive.

I use kdenlive.